# looking for better option to print associated values from two items in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

For the python dictionary below:

```
fruits = {'names': ['apple', 'banana', 'mango'], 
          'prices': [12.99, 2.99, 9.99] 
          }
```

How to get the prices associated with each fruit?

Basically,  I want pair wise printing:

```
 apple = 12.99
 banana = 2.99
 mango = 9.99
```

I was thinking of using double for loop, for example:

```
 for fruit in fruits['names']:
     print(fruit)
     for ….
         print(...)
```

but somehow this looks no good. Any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary that maps the names to prices right from the beginning:

```
prices = dict(zip(fruits['names'], fruits['prices']))  # in case you need to convert
```

Then simply iterate over that dictionary:

```
for fruit, price in prices.items():
    print(f'{fruit} = {price:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Apart from changing the data structure (which I would recommend anyway, since name and price are just losely coupled by the same position in different arrays), there is the standard:

```
for fruit_name, fruit_price in zip(fruits["names"], fruits["prices"]):
   print(...)
```